# Bandwidth usage via 3G high when using ad-hoc network

Tags: networking, laptop, bandwidth

I am in Turkey and me and my brother use 1 3G network usb adapter for 2 laptops with a 3G network usb card.

It seems using ad-hoc, the bandwidth usage goes up BADLY. Even the 3G usage, measuring only the bandwith that goes via 3G, so not just LAN bandwidth....

I am truly puzzled why bandwidth usage gets so insanely high when using an ad-hoc network. When one of us uses the 3G, all is fine, but when another laptop connects to the other via ad-hoc, some basic surfing will go very slow, but still result in bandwidth usage of 2mbps... something is very wrong here.

Both DU Meter (measures only 3G bandwidth, not all network bandwidth) and the VINN USB modem software give bandwidth usage of 2mbps when doing only regular things...

I am pretty experienced with Windows, networking, Linux, but I have no idea how to find out what causees the bandwidth usage to 10-fold, when another computer is connected via ad-hoc...

Answer (score 0):

Something like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) could be used to analyse the type/destination of the traffic on the network and via the 3G card specifically.